# How to prove the following equation

Tags: definite-integrals

This problem starts as a 1st order ODE where i need to solve for $\phi(t)$.
$$\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}-D\phi(t)=-f(t)$$
with a final condition $\phi(T)=1$. $D$ is a constant. Using an integrating factor $I(t)=e^{-Dt}$ to solve the ODE for $\phi(t)$, I arrived at the following equation (1):
$$\phi(t) = -e^{Dt}\int f(t)e^{-Dt}dt$$How do i go from the above to prove that:
$$\phi(t) = e^{-D(T-t)}+\int_t^Te^{-D(\tau-t)}f(\tau) d\tau$$
I've tried to use integration by parts on equation (1) for the expression in the integral but that doesn't seem to converge to the required form.
Thank you.

Comment: Does the integral in equation $(1)$ have no born ? Is it a constant that does not depend on $t$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "no born"? only $D$ is a constant, everything else depends on $t$. $T$ is also a constant.

Comment: How $\int f(t)e^{-Dt}dt$ depends on $t$?

Comment: By "born" I meant the limit of the integral in equation (1). If we have $\int_{a}^{b} f(t)e^{-Dt}\text{d}t$ and $a$, $b$ do not depends on $t$ then the integral does not depend on $t$. In fact we cannot have $t$ both in the limit of the integral and in the integration variable.

Comment: Thanks npisinp, I get your question now. <br>

Comment: Thanks npisinp, I get your question now. <br> the limits of integration does depend on $t$. The first equation is something i derived. If $f(t)$ was a defined integrable function of $t$, I would've used integration by parts or substitution to solve it. That would give me an answer with a remaining constant $C$, which i would then solve using the final condition.<br> However, since $f(t)$ is not defined it is left as is. In the integral of the second equation that i'm trying to get to, the limits of integ. don't depend on $t$, hence the change of variable to $\tau$.

Comment: Can you give me the original problem? I cannot do it without the limit of the integral in equation $(1)$.

Comment: npisinp, I've just updated the post to include the original problem. Hopefully that helps to clarify the problem. thanks.

Comment: One solves equations and proves equalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use definite integrals all the way through instead of indefinite integrals. This works the appropriate constant terms into the equations from the get go.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-Dt}\phi(t)\right)=-e^{-Dt}f(t)\\
\implies e^{-Dt}\phi(t) - e^{-DT}\phi(T)= -\int_T^t f(\tau)e^{-D\tau}d\tau$$

Comment: Thank you, David! Spot on answer.